# Rails pdftk error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdftk

I'm using pdftk within my rails application to generate a composite pdf of several individual pdf files.  When, for whatever reason, pdftk does not generate the composite file, no error is generated.  I do have this area of code wrapped in a begin/rescue block, but since i'm using %x[...] to execute pdftk, it doesn't receive any exeptions from the external call.  How can i either a) call pdftk where i can capture the exception or b) receive the output error code from the %x call?

Answer (score 0):

```
`pdftk #{subcommand}`
raise Exception unless $?.success?
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't tell me WHY pdftk failed.  I was raising an exception bases on whether the output file was generated or not, but i really need to capture the pdftk failure message somehow.

Comment: You can use the `popen4` gem to capture `stderr`.

Comment: The output code when using `%x[...]` is going to be `$?.to_i`.